# Having a Cook server send signals to Pi

Tags: networking, server, led

My idea is to have a Pi running and controlling some LED lights.

I have a Python script that controls the LED lights.

How does another computer (Windows based) send a signal to the Pi to switch the appropriate lights off and on?

I was thinking that a web-based approach using PHP would work best.  How do I interface PHP and Python?

(clarified 6.12.2014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(assuming you run raspbian)

You can very easily install a LAMP (Linux Apache MySQL PHP) server on your raspberry pi, there are [numerous](http://elinux.org/RPi_A_Simple_Wheezy_LAMP_install) [tutorials](http://www.instructables.com/id/Turning-your-Raspberry-Pi-into-a-personal-web-serv/?lang=en) [online](http://www.geothread.net/building-a-lamp-server-on-the-raspberry-pi-computer/), but it basically boils down to this:

On your Raspbian Pi, execute the following commands (you will need internet access):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

For MySQL, also install

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
```

And then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

You will find a file called `index.html` in you `/var/www/` directory. Here you can start your first test: On a remote computer, open a web browser and point it to your RPi's IP Address (you can get that by using `ifconfig`). You should see a message like "It works." (This is the content of the `index.html`!).

Now for your case of accessing a python script: 
Of course, you should be able to call a python script directly as a CGI-Script. Anyhow, I'd suggest (as this has worked well for me) to use a php script to call your python script. This could be something like this:

File: `/var/www/5_on.php`

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('sudo /path/to/your/python/script.py 5 on');
?>
```

As you can see, this calls a python script on your pi, giving along command line arguments you can retrieve via (python):

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1] + sys.argv[2] #sys.argv[0] will habe the name of the script
```

Of course, instead of having a seperate php file for every on/off/gpio combination, you can use $_GET and call the php script with

```
http://192.168.*.*/gpio.php?number=5&on=on
```

and using (as `/var/www/gpio.php`):

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('sudo /path/to/your/python/script.py '.$_GET['number'].' '.$_GET['on']);
?>
```

Be careful, tough, as this may pose a security risk!

Now, for executing the python script, you will need (to be able to access gpio) sudo rights. If you don't want your `www-data`-user to have full root permissions (also not suggested), you can allow a single file to be executed as root, by editing the `/etc/sudoers` file with the command `visudo`:
Add at the bottom:

```
%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/python/script.py
```

Also, don't forget to add the executable bit (`sudo chmod +x`) and the shebang (first line of your script should be `#!/usr/bin/env python`) to your python script! It might also be necessary for your script to belong to `www-data`:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /path/to/your/python/script.py
```

Now you can call `http://ip.of.your.rpi/gpio.php?number=5&on=on` from your windows server (I don't know the exact commands for that, but on linux I'd use curl or wget).

I hope I didn't forget anything, if I did, feel free to add more information!

Comment: security risk isn't an issue.  The application/pi's will be running internally.  Thanks for the detail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the internet was invented on Unix. The r-pi runs Gnu and Gnu is Unix (Gnu = Gnu's not UNIX = Gnu is not UNIX, but it is Unix).

You don't need a web server, here is a simple solution in python. There where no security considerations (this is not secure, unless your network is).

This runs a server that you connect to from the other system, I assumed that the other end is active and will want to connect to a listening (passive) server.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import socket
import sys

port = 2003 # choose a better port
listener=socket.socket() 
listener.bind(('',port)) 
listener.listen(1)
while True:
    socket, info = listener.accept() 
    f=socket.makefile()
    for line in f: 
        #interperate the lines and do something
        print line
        sys.stdout.flush()
    f.close
    socket.close()
```

Here is a minimum at the other end. It connects and sends a message.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import socket
s = socket.create_connection(('raspbery-pi',port))
s.send("hello\n")
s.close()
```